# Creating a high and low game in python and need a lot of help!

Tags: python

Here is the Pseudocode

1. Print instructions to the user
2. Start with the variables high = 1000, low = 1, and tries = 1
3. While high is greater than low
4. Guess the average of high and low
5. Ask the user to respond to the guess
6. Handle the four possible outcomes:

   - If the guess was right, print a message that tries guesses were required and quit the program
   - If the guess was too high, print a message that says “I will guess lower.”
   - If the guess was too low, print a message that says “I will guess higher.”
   - If the user entered an incorrect value, print out the instructions again.

I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: I'd suggest beginning at the beginning (and ending at the end). Tackle your problems one at a time: make a program that can do #1; then once it works, expand it to do #2, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's where you begin. Insert the specifications as documentation, then do one at a time, testing along the way.

```
# Print instructions to the user
### 'print "xyz"' will output the xyz text.

# Start with the variables high = 1000, low = 1, and tries = 1
### You can set a variable with 'abc = 1'.

# While high is greater than low
### Python has a while statement and you can use something like 'while x > 7:'.
### Conditions like 'x > 7', 'guess == number' can also be used in `ifs` below.

    # Guess the average of high and low
    ### The average of two numbers is (x + y) / 2.

    # Ask the user to respond to the guess
    ### Python (at least 2.7) has a 'raw_input' for this, NOT 'input'.

    # If the guess was right, print a message that tries guesses were required
    # and quit the program
    ### Look at the 'if' statement for this and all the ones below.

    # If the guess was too high, print a message that says “I will guess lower.”
    # If the guess was too low, print a message that says “I will guess higher.”
    # If the user entered an incorrect value, print out the instructions again.
```

I've also added a small comment detailing what language elements you should look in to for each section.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if this is Python 2 or 3.  The following should be good for recent versions of 2; I'm not familiar with 3, but it will probably at least get you started there too.  Seeing as how this is homework, I'm just going to recommend some things for you to research.

- You'll want to get the guesses and check them in a loop.  I recommend looking up the [while](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) loop.
- To get the user inputs, try [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input).
- To output messages, look up [print](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print).
- Use [if](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) for checking the user's responses.

Answer (score 0):

You begin with point one:

```
print "instructions to the user"
```

(just change the string to be more informative, that's not a programming problem!-), then continue with point two (three assignments, just like your homework assignment says), then with point three:

```
while high > low:
```

There -- that's half your work already (points 1-3 out of 6).  What's giving you problems beyond that?  Do you know what *average* means, so (say) `guess = (high + low) // 2` is understandable to you, or what?  That's all you need for point 4!  Do you know how to ask the user a question and get their response?  Look up `input` and `raw_input`... OK, I've covered the first **five** of the six points, surely you can **at least** "get started" now!-)

Comment: Thank you so much :) All the answers here have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't the answer but you need to look at the program:

1. Print out instructions.
2. Make a random number or a use your own. (For rand numbers you need to use a modulus divide trick)
3. Probably using a while loop: check if the number guessed is higher or lower or equal
4. In case of higher print higher, in case of lower print lower, in case of equal break or call exit (probably breaking will do fine).

Pseudo Code:

```
print "intructions"
thenumber = rand() % 1000+1
while (true)
    getInput(guess);
    if (guess > thenumber)
        print "Guess lower"
    else if (guess < thenumber)
        print "Guess higher")
    else
        exit //or break.
```

Just pseudo code though.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("*********** Hi Lo Game ***********")
import random
x = (random.randint(1,100))
num1 = int(input("Enter your number:"))
while num1 < x:
   print ("Too Low")
   num1 = int(input("Enter your number:"))
while num1 > x:
   print ("Too High")
   num1 = int(input("Enter your number:"))
if num1 == x:
   print ("Congratulations! You are Correct")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. You need a single while loop, not two in sequence. If the user makes a guess that is too high followed by a guess that is too low, your code falls through without the user finishing the game. You also haven't handled the case of invalid input as the OP requested.

Answer (score -1):

## Well working Hi/Low game w/score

```
from random import randint
import time
print '='*20
print 'The Up / Down Game'
print 'Enter up or down !'
print 'Get 10 in a row for a reward!'
print '='*20
print "=    "+'GAME START'+"    ="
print '='*20
print ''
ans = ' '
score = 0
while True:

n1 = randint(2,13)
n2 = randint(2,13)
print "I have = %s" % (n1)

ans = raw_input("What do you choose: ")
if ans == 'up':
    print "Your number is : "
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "."
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print ". %s" % (n2)
    time.sleep(1)
    if n1 > n2:
        print "Sorry you lost."
        time.sleep(2)
        print "Final score = %s" % (score)
        time.sleep(2)
        print "="*20
        print "Try Again"
        print "="*20
        score = 0
    
    elif n1 <= n2:
        score += 1
        if score > 1:
            print "That's %s in a row" % (score)
        elif score == 1:
            print "Thats  1 point"
        elif score == 10:
            print "Congratz you got the reward!!!"
    
elif ans == 'down':
    print "Your number is : "
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "."
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print ". %s" % (n2)
    time.sleep(1)
    if n1 < n2:
        print "Sorry you lost."
        time.sleep(2)
        print "Final score = %s" % (score)
        time.sleep(2)
        print "="*20
        print "Try Again"
        print "="*20
        score = 0
    
    elif n1 >= n2:
        score += 1
        if score > 1:
            print "That's %s in a row" % (score)
        elif score == 1:
            print "Thats  1 point"
        elif score == 10:
            print "Congratz. You got the reward"


    else:
        tryAgain = raw_input("enter up or down only")
```

Comment: I would recommend adding some explanation to your code. The code doesn't map `1:1` on the description, so it would be easier to understand if you would add some comments/methods.

Comment: oh sorry. this is my first post also it is my first code ever that has a start and a finish. I don't know what to explain. since all my coding is newbie.

Comment: and i see now that he wanted some more options and the average.. blaah. sry